# xpra on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg, keyboard-layout, xpra

Linux Subsystem for Linux was released recently and some people already tries to run X graphical applications. I use `xpra` to get decentralized access to some of my graphical apps which run on Linux server. With Bash on Windows I managed to install `xpra` package directly in Windows and successfully run `xpra` client.

However, I cannot change a keyboard layout, and I presume some `xpra` config tweaks needed, probably on the server's side.

What should be changed for layout switching to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this isn't actually regarding Bash on Ubuntu on Windows question, but Xming.

Startup options should be set for Xming executable to properly switch layouts.

For example, for US/Russian keyboard I set this:

```
 :0 -clipboard -multiwindow -xkblayout us,ru -xkbvariant ,winkeys -xkboptions grp:ctrl_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll,grp:switch
```

The crucial part here is `-xkblayout us,ru`, for some other layout combinations other options should be used.

These options should be set on Xming shortcut in Windows, mine is located at `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Xming`. Right click it and set these options in the **Shortcut** tab, **Target** field:

[image]

(Here only part of the options string is shown.)

After this is done, you may start Xming from the Start/Search as usual but now it will start with these additional options.

Source: http://wiki-freebsd.tushinec.ru/index.php/Xming.

P.S. if you want Xming to autostart with these options on Windows log on put in the Windows Registry key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

string value

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Xming\Xming.exe" :0 -clipboard -multiwindow -xkblayout us,ru -xkbvariant ,winkeys -xkboptions grp:ctrl_shift_toggle,grp_led:scroll,grp:switch
```

Comment: xpra does not use Xming

Comment: That's right, `xpra` doesn't use `Xming`. But I personally use `Xming` so that my Windows has its own X Server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that WSL doesn't have direct access to USB devices like a VM might, so layout switching would have to be done in Windows. Just find the language settings in the control panel and set it up there.

Comment: Well, if you mean that I should change the layout with the mouse in the tray, I tried this of course and it didn't work.

Comment: Does it work for Windows? I mean if you change the layout with alt+shift or with the mouse or whatever you use, and you type stuff in some regular Windows program, does it work? If not, there's something wrong with your Windows system. If it does work in Windows, there's something wrong with WSL.

Comment: Of course it works. I'd not ask question like that if layout switching wouldn't work even in regular Windows apps.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that this was a bug in xpra which has been fixed in v5 [Language layout does not switch automatically](https://github.com/Xpra-org/xpra/issues/3857#issuecomment-1554750769)